# Multiple Monitors with Multiple Kiosks. How to run powerpoint on one and IE on the others

Tags: windows-7, windows, multiple-monitors, microsoft-powerpoint-2010, kiosk

I have a setup with 4 monitors that all need to be running in kiosk mode.
3 of the monitors will be running IE and the fourth needs to be running a powerpoint presentation.
IE is easy - I've got a way to select which monitor should display which window, but I can't get powerpoint viewer to run in any window other than the main display.

Is there a way to set Powerpoint Viewer to ALWAYS open in a particular monitor?

Comment: There is software that exists that allows you to save preferences like this.

Comment: Do you know any of their names?

I have tried a couple of the ones that I've come across - including Ultramon and Display Fusions - but neither of them seem to work with the PPTViewer. They work fine with IE though.